# JS Toggle not being reflected when I dynamically load in HTML using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to use JS to toggle a .show class into a div within my HTML which will change the display: none to display: block. This is for a dropdown menu. I am dynamically loading in two different versions based on whether the user is currently logged in or logged out using PHP.

Here is my PHP/HTML code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- EXTERNAL CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/navigation-bar-v2.css">
  <!-- EXTERNAL SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec7e0e3eb8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../js/navigation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <div class="section-a">
        <a href="../index.php"><img class="logo" src="../images/logoDarkBlue.png" alt="img"></a>
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: start;">
          <a href="../index.php">Feed</a>
          <a href="#">Discover</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="nav-search" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
    
    <div class="section-b">
      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
          // LOGGED IN
          echo '
            <div class="notifications">
              <button class="notification-dropdown">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="logged-in">
                <span style="font-size: 20px; margin-right: 0.2em; vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user"></i></span>
                <span>', $_SESSION["uname"], '</span> &nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> &nbsp;Terms & Policies</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          ';
        }
        else {
          // LOGGED OUT
          echo '
            <div id="login-cont">
              <a href="../login.php">
                <button class="login-btn">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Log In</span>
                </button>
              </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="log-in">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i> &nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
              </button>
              <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> &nbsp;Terms & Policies</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          ';
        }
      ?>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  $(".log-in").click(() => {
    openNavDropdown();
  });

  $(".logged-in").click(() => {
    console.log("Click!!!");
    openNavDropdown();
  });

  function openNavDropdown() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("myDropdown"));
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    console.log(document.getElementById("myDropdown"));
  }

  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (
      !event.target.matches(".log-in") ||
      !event.target.matches(".logged-in")
    ) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

To debug, I ran some console.log commands within my JS and found that the class was actually being added to the proper div. However, within the added class is not being reflected within the actual source code:

[image]

[image]

All the code required to replicate the problem should be provided above.

**EDIT:** For testing you will need to include `session_start();` at the top of your .php document.

Code Sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/sfoyjmh8/10/

**EDIT:**  I have identified the error. Within the JS, if I were to remove `|| (!event.target.matches(".logged-in"))` from the if condition of the onclick function that closes the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it, the dropdown works. So how can I go about modifying this to not be an error?

Comment: Please create a runnable example with just the essential HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You can create a snippet with in the question editor. Look for the `<>` icon and paste your code in there.

Comment: So is the actual problem that the content does not then show up as expected in the page? It shouldn't matter much if it shows in the element inspector or not really (although it's a bit odd that it doesn't when it's logging it correctly (it happens in this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3z541Lhn/)). P.S. It's a front-end issue so we're really not fussed about your PHP...just show us a generated example (both logged-in and -out variations, if it actually makes any difference to the problem) of the HTML which the JS is targeting - that's much more useful.

Comment: @ADyson Added a runnable executable to the original post. I actually found the error code. Within the "Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it" section (See comments within JS), if I remove "|| (!event.target.matches(".logged-in"))" from the if statement, it works. So, now the question is, how do I fix the error?

Comment: Ah. You probably want `&&` instead of `||` there, because you only want it to proceed if the click happened on _neither_ of those buttons, not if it didn't happen to only one of them!

Comment: Yep, that fixed my problem - If you post your reply as an Answer, I can mark it as the answer to the question! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Although I would say it'd probably make more sense, to add a _common_ class to both of those buttons, and then simply have _one_ check for that. It might not matter if it stays at just two buttons here, but if you ever wanted to add more, you would not have to constantly add new stuff to the condition in your script then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
if (
      !event.target.matches(".log-in") ||
      !event.target.matches(".logged-in")
    )
```

you probably want `&&` instead of `||`, because you only want it to proceed if the click happened on *neither* of those buttons, not if it didn't happen to only one of them.